# How can count the asscociation in sequelize js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

When I make the following query  to get the poll with option and each option have the voteCount. But it gives wring count.

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Poll.findAll({
    where: { subjectId: req.query.subjectId },
    include: {
      model: PollOption,
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", "pollVote.id"), "voteCount"]]
      },
      required: false,
      include: {
        model: PollVote,
        // attributes: [],
        required: false
      }
    },
    group:['pollOptions.id']
  }).then(poll => {
    console.log(poll);
    res.send({ poll });
  });
});
```

I get this as the response

```
{
    "poll": [
//Array of the poll
           {
            "id": 3,
            "module_id": "mbbs",
            "question": "Test Question Poll",
            "pollOptions": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "pollId": 3,
                    "option": "Option 1",
                    "voteCount": 1,
                    "pollVotes": [
                        {
                            "id": 6,
                            "pollOptionId": 1,
                            "pollId": 3,
                            "userId": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "pollId": 3,
                    "userId": 120,
                    "option": "Option 2",
                    "voteCount": 2,
                     //Vote must be 1 but return 2
                    "pollVotes": [
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "pollOptionId": 2,
                            "pollId": 3,
                            "userId": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "module_id": "mbbs",
            "question": "Test Question Poll 4",
            "subjectId": 1,
            "pollOptions": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "pollId": 4,
                    "option": "Option 1sd",

                    "voteCount": 1,
                    "pollVotes": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where voteCount is wrong.
How can I make it right.

Sql query is as follow

SELECT `poll`.`id`, `poll`.`module_id`, `poll`.`question`, `poll`.`userId`, `poll`.`subjectId`, `poll`.`date`, `poll`.`expireDate`, `pollOptions`.`id` AS `pollOptions.id`, `pollOptions`.`pollId` AS `pollOptions.pollId`, `pollOptions`.`userId` AS `pollOptions.userId`, `pollOptions`.`option` AS `pollOptions.option`, COUNT('pollVote.id') AS `pollOptions.voteCount`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`id` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.id`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`pollOptionId` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.pollOptionId`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`pollId` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.pollId`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`userId` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.userId` FROM `poll` AS `poll` LEFT OUTER JOIN `pollOption` AS `pollOptions` ON `poll`.`id` = `pollOptions`.`pollId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `pollVote` AS `pollOptions->pollVotes` ON `pollOptions`.`id` = `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`pollOptionId` WHERE `poll`.`subjectId` = '1' GROUP BY `poll`.`id`;

Comment: Can you share the query generated by Sequelize?

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Your `sequelize` statement should be as follows -

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Poll.findAll({
    where: { subjectId: req.query.subjectId },
    include: {
      model: PollOption,
      attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", `pollOptions->pollVotes.id`), "voteCount"]]
      },
      required: false,
      include: {
        model: PollVote,
        // attributes: [],
        required: false
      }
    },
    group:['pollOptions.id']
  }).then(poll => {
    console.log(poll);
    res.send({ poll });
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nope It give same result as above .                           Sql  query become

Comment: Sql query become  SELECT `poll`.`id`, `poll`.`module_id`, `poll`.`question`, `poll`.`userId`, `poll`.`subjectId`, `poll`.`date`, `poll`.`expireDate`, `pollOptions`.`id` AS `pollOptions.id`, `pollOptions`.`pollId` AS `pollOptions.pollId`, `pollOptions`.`userId` AS `pollOptions.userId`, `pollOptions`.`option` AS `pollOptions.option`, COUNT('`pollOptions->pollVotes`.`id`') AS `pollOptions.voteCount`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`id` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.id`,  `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`pollOptionId`

Comment: AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.pollOptionId`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`pollId` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.pollId`, `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`userId` AS `pollOptions.pollVotes.userId` FROM `poll` AS `poll` LEFT OUTER JOIN `pollOption` AS `pollOptions` ON `poll`.`id` = `pollOptions`.`pollId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `pollVote` AS `pollOptions->pollVotes` ON `pollOptions`.`id` = `pollOptions->pollVotes`.`pollOptionId` WHERE `poll`.`subjectId` = '1' GROUP BY `pollOptions`.`id`;